# How to derive the error $e^{n}=M^{n}e^{0}$ from iteration $x^{n+1} = Mx^{n} + f$?

Tags: numerical-methods, mathematical-modeling

$x^{n+1} = Mx^{n} + f$ is fixed-point iteration for solving the equation $x = Mx + f$, i.e., $(I-M)x = f$.

The error $e^{n} = x - x^{n}$

How does one get $e^{n}=M^{n}e^{0}$?

Comment: $e^n=x-x^n=(Mx+f)-(Mx^{n-1}+f)=M(x-x^{n-1})$ and so on ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

$$e^0 = x^1 - x^0$$
$$e^1 = x^2 - x^1$$
$$e^2 = x^3 - x^2$$

$$x^1 = Mx^0+f$$
$$e^0 = x^0(M-1) +f$$
$$x^2 = M(Mx^0+f) - x^0$$
$$x^2 = M^2x^0+Mf+f$$
$$e^1 = Me^0$$

$$x^3 = M^3x^0 +M^2f+Mf+f$$

$$e^2 = x^3-x^2$$

$$e^2 = M^2(x^0(M-1)+f)$$

$$e^2 = M^2e^0$$

By induction:

$$e^n = x^{n+1} - x^n$$

$$e^n = M^ne^0$$